# Linux MINT installing a program

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation

How to install this program?

https://github.com/phoebe-project/phoebe1

I have problem by the first step.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this http://phoebe-project.org/install?

Comment: I tried to install PHOEBE 1. There are instructions in zip file, but I don't understand the error on the picture.

Comment: First of all, please don't post images of text. Second, can you create files at that location?

Comment: What files? I am sorry, I am biginner.

Comment: Any files. The problem is the compiler can't create executables. Can it create anything? Probably if you move or copy the phoebe1-master to another location, and go on from there, say your /home directory, then it should be ok.

Comment: You mean create a file in /media/oem/DATADISK/phoebe1-master/phoebe-gui ? I did but the error stay. I tried to move the directory to home, however, there is an error too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94411/discussion-between-lukas-altman-and-tomasz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`build-essential` and `gfortran` were missing.